# In app billing v3 NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-billing

To test out in app billing v3 for Android I implemented a dialog which adds a single choice items adapter. I've added the test Skus, "android.test.purchased", "android.test.canceled", "android.test.refunded", "android.test.item_unavailable".

When I use the dialog to launch a purchase flow everything is fine, I am able to purchase the item and the item is most definitely purchased. However, I get a nullpointerexception when my app then tries to refresh the UI. I know the refresh works.

Here's my logcat:

```
12-16 01:06:06.706: I/Running inventory query with(20846): android.test.purchased
12-16 01:06:06.706: I/Running details query with(20846): SkuDetails:{"title":"Sample Title","price":"£0.61","type":"inapp","description":"Sample description for product: android.test.purchased.","productId":"android.test.purchased"}
12-16 01:06:06.706: I/Running details query with(20846): SkuDetails:{"title":"Sample Title","price":"£0.61","type":"inapp","description":"Sample description for product: android.test.purchased.","productId":"android.test.purchased"}
12-16 01:06:06.706: I/Running inventory query with(20846): android.test.canceled
12-16 01:06:06.706: I/Running details query with(20846): null
12-16 01:06:06.706: I/Running details query with(20846): null
12-16 01:06:06.706: D/AndroidRuntime(20846): Shutting down VM
12-16 01:06:06.706: W/dalvikvm(20846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d12930)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onQueryInventoryFinished(MainActivity.java:201)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at com.example.test.util.IabHelper$2$1.run(IabHelper.java:536)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-16 01:06:06.706: E/AndroidRuntime(20846): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

for (String s : allSkus) {
Log.i("Running inventory query with", "" + s);
SkuDetails c = inv.getSkuDetails(s);
Log.i("Running details query with", "" + c);
if (inv.hasPurchase(s)) {
    purchaseArray.add(c.getTitle());
} else {
    **LINE 201** objects.add(c.getPrice() + "  T:" + c.getSku());
}
```

allSkus is an ArrayList which holds the 4 skus above.

The nullpointer is 
    SkuDetails c = inv.getSkuDetails(s);

Which returns null on the UI refresh. But the issue is that it seems to work for the first sku (android.test.purchased) but is null for the second sku (android.test.canceled) and that too it is only null when it runs after having bought another item (refunded or purchased). However if I subsequently open it again, it's fine and no nullpointerexception is thrown.

If I add a null check before adding to the ArrayList objects, then no items are added as every item after or before the bought item is returning null on inv.getSkuDetails(s)

Comment: It's actually so simple which is great for a novice like myself. First (assuming you use eclipse) just where you download the SDK, look within the extras for in app billing. Once you do that, if you navigate to your android-sdk folder it's there under extras > google > in app billing v3 -> samples. All you have to do is import it and copy the util files and add some queries and listeners as described here http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample

Comment: Hey AndroidPenguin,


Thanks for help. Almost implemented, just have a single confusion or can say did not understood from google's link that how to restore transaction. If every product can not be purchased again an again then how to to get info that i have already purchased the product. 
thanks.. :)

Comment: My pleasure! Don't forget to upvote. The query purchase that occurs right after set up does this. As long as you don't consume your purchases of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, leaving this for anyone who has the same problem as me. In the UI refresh I was calling the IabHelper query without querying the details of the skus. Thus precached skus had details, but those that weren't, failed.

Answer (score 5):

This had me stumped and the accepted answer did not contain the pertinent details.

What you need to do is pass a List with the SKUs you want to query (whether they are purchased or not) after calling startSetup. So it would look something like the code below instead of what is provided in the (inadequate) boilerplate TrivialDrive example.

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mGotInventoryListener);
```

Also, it looks like there are some phantom methods (that are still not yet cleaned up in the comments, which are also inaccurate)... more details of that bug here:

http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=98

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The main point is to pass in the skuList to get the sku details that you seek. If you don't pass in the skuList the callback method will only return you sku details of purchased product!